# Modify JTable to fit screen

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

I have created an app just for exercise purpose with a `JTable` in it to show the data coming from my database.

My problem is that the table shows up in half the panel on my screen. I've tried everything to expand the columns without success. Can someone tell me how to modify the table?

Here is the code that creates the table:

```
    public void createTable() {
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"To do","Date added"});
    table.setSize(450, 600);
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    for(int i = 0; i < model.getId().size(); i++) {
        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{model.getItem().get(i), model.getDate().get(i)});
    }
    add(table.getTableHeader());
    add(table);
}
```

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Also I want to ask about table.getTableHeader() because if I don't add that it doesn't show up since it is a part of the table.. is that normal?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"getTableHeader() .. doesn't show up"*  Put the table in a scroll-pane. 3) *"I've tried everything to expand the columns"*  It's quite obvious you haven't since it does work, and so far you have failed.

Comment: "*the JTable shows up in half the JPanel on my screen*" Then what is interesting is not the way you create the JTable (which is classical) but how you create the JPanel. Particularly what layout manager you use. And apparently you don't want to fit to the screen but to fit to the panel...

Comment: all three points by (@Andrew Thompson) are most important, post an `SSCCE`, short, runnable, compilable just about `JFrame` with `JTable` in `JPanel`, workaroung isn't something, nothing special

Comment: @mKorbel  Just to cheat, I added a 3rd point in edit.  ;)

Comment: @mKorbel That was my thinking when I established [1.1C](http://1point1c.org/).  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson i've tried a scrollpane but I think i've implemented it wrong.. could you give me an example of that? what I tried before myself is JScrollPane scrlPan=new JScrollPane(table); but it didn't change anything

Comment: *"could you give me an example of that?"*  Yes I could.  I might consider hunting one down or writing up a new example.  But first I want to see your SSCCE.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson there isn't implemented important space circus, two comets (one with really with big applitude) in 2nd. half of this year, phaaaaaa, btw very nice site, gooooood (event last ticks are 2008-2010, isn't now year 2013???)

Comment: @mKorbel  Looking forward to the comets. :)  And yes, that site has languished a little recently.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson 1st. `C/2011 L4 PanSTARRS`, north part, 8-15/march/2013, 2nd. north part `C/2012 S1 ISON` november 2013, there are two assumptions 2a) `28/11/2013` could be exploding on the closest point with the sun 2b) `27/december/2013` will be nearest to the earth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `JPanel` has `FlowLayout` implemented in API, then your `JPanel` layed `JComponents` correctly, with yours logics (add `JTableHeader`, add `JTable`)
- change that to the `BorderLayout` and to put `JTableHeader` to the `NORTH` / `SOUTH` and `JTable` to the `CENTER`
- use `JScrollPane` for `JTables view`, everything else is bothering with `LayoutManager` and calculating for `PreferredSize` very ugly way,

Comment: A default `FlowLayout` is the likely culprit.